# Double an image using python

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-3.5

i have to double an image using python,

So i think i can replace each pixel of the image with a square formed by 4 pixels

how do i can do that and assign to each pixel of the little square different colors?

Comment: why don't you use some Python module to resize image - ie. `Pillow`. If you have to do "manually" then first you need new empty image with double size and then you can put `4 pixels squares` in this image. You can't put `4 pixels squares` in place of `one pixel` in oryginal image.

Comment: i was said it's possible to replace one pixel of the image with a 2x2 pixels square; so i will have a second image which is the double of the first image

Comment: `replace` can mean "get one pixel from oryginal image, use it to create 4 pixels, put this 4 pixels in new image (not in oryginal image)". So first you have to create new empty image with double size.

Comment: ahh get it, that's what i would want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a homework ? Working with a new target image, as suggested in the comments, is the easiest.

But theoretically, assuming your original image is represented as some 2 dimension table of pixels, you could do it without creating a new image:

First double both dimensions of the original image (with the original image staying on "upper left" and occupying 1/4 of the new image, and filling the other 3/4 with blank or any value).

Then take the lower right pixel from the original image, and write 4 identical pixels in the lower right of the resized image.

Then take the original pixel directly at the the left of the previous original pixel, copy it on the 4 pixels directly at the left of the 4 previous new pixels. Repeat until you reach the left end of the line, then start the process again on the line above.

At some point you will overwrite pixels from the original image, but that doesn't matter since you will already have duplicated those in the new image.

That's pure theory, assuming you are not allowed to use external libraries such as Pillow.

Comment: i can't use external libraries, i think this would work, but i should find a wa y t odo what you wrote down